# How to correctly use rank over

Tags: mysql, sql

Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by name order by counts desc) as rank from ( select Name, count(Case_' at line 4

```
select Name, counts
from (
select Name, counts,
rank()over(partition by name order by counts desc) as rank
from (
select Name, count(Case_Id) as counts,
from CTD a
left join Agent_Table b 
on a.Agent_ID = b.Agent_ID
group by Name )
group by Name )
where rank < = 2;
```

---

REFER BELOW FOR CREATING TABLE

create table if not exists `Agent_Table`(
`Agent_ID` int(5),
`Name` varchar(20)
);

insert into `Agent_Table` (`Agent_ID`, `Name`)
values ( '1', 'Vijay'),
( '2', 'Rajesh'),
('3', 'Satish'),
('4', 'Anji') ;

create table if not exists `CTD` (
`Case_Id` int(5),
`Stage` varchar(20),
`Login_Time` varchar(50),
`Logout_Time` varchar(50),
`Agent_ID` int(5),
`Status` varchar(20)
);

insert into `CTD` (`Case_Id`,`Stage`,`Login_Time`,
`Logout_Time`,`Agent_ID`,`Status`)
values ('101', 'Maker', '5/11/2019 10:20', '10:30', '2', 'Success'),
('102', 'Maker', '5/11/2019 10:25', '10:35', '1', 'Success'),
('103', 'Maker', '5/11/2019 10:40', '10:50', '2', 'Success'),
('101', 'Checker', '5/11/2019 10:45', '11:00', '3', 'Success'),
('101', 'Approver', '5/11/2019 11:15', '11:30', '2', 'Success'),
('102', 'Checker', '5/11/2019 10:50', '11:00', '1', 'Reject'),
('102', 'Maker', '5/11/2019 11:15', '11:45', '4', 'Reverify'),
('103', 'Checker', '5/11/2019 11:30', '11:40', '2', 'Reject')

Comment: You have an unnecessary comma after `as counts` in your subquery. Also consider using aliases on derived tables, even though some databases are forgiving about that

Comment: MySQL supports the `over( ... )` syntax in version 8.0.2. Earlier versions of MySQL will return the error you saw. What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided an `alias` for subquery and that might be the reason you are getting an error.

try the following

```
 select 
    Name, 
    counts
from 
(
    select 
        Name, 
        counts,
        rank() over(partition by Name order by counts desc) as rn
    from 
    (
        select 
            Name, 
            count(Case_Id) as counts
        from CTD a
        left join Agent_Table b 
        on a.Agent_ID = b.Agent_ID
        group by 
            Name
    ) subq
) sub
where rn <= 2;
```

Comment: Yes but im still getting the same error near partition by

Comment: @PriyanshiPatsaria try now. I have updated my answer.

Comment: No it's not working, same error. I have edited my code added table creation code for reference. u can go to www.sqlfiddle.com and paste the code to check yourself in less than a minute.

Comment: @PriyanshiPatsaria try now. Actual issue in your query was column `rank`, it is keyword in MySQL. You can over come by using `\`` around the keyword.  I have updated my query and here is the fiddle link. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o6q26pwKn6HYo1n2FLzNSc/0

Comment: Hi, I have used the same query that you have written, but on sqlfiddle and it is still showing that very error. Link for reference of your query here here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd2e97/1

Comment: Yes. Accepted. Thank you, zealous.

Answer (score 0):

You had an unnecessary comma and were missing necessary aliases. In any case, Window functions are applied after `group by` so you can actually simplify your query as

```
select Name, 
       counts
from (select Name, 
             count(Case_Id) as counts,
             rank() over (partition by name order by count(Case_Id) desc) as rnk
       from CTD a
       left join Agent_Table b on a.Agent_ID = b.Agent_ID
       group by Name) t1
where rank < = 2;
```